# 1 year experience openings

Tags: interviewing

having 6 months of experience am I eligible for Job openings that require 1 year of experience?I know this may sound rhetorical but should I try to approach the HR to know if they would let me interview for the position?

Comment: If these are external openings, you might be, but this would be company specific. I have noticed over time that internal openings tend to be more stringent on meeting the 1 year mark as many companies have policies that you can't transfer in less time than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It couldn't hurt. Depending on your actual experience and other qualifications, HR could actually waive the 1 year requirement for you. The worst that can happen is that HR will simply say that you're not qualified for the position, and hopefully they would encourage you to check back when you have 1 year's experience under your belt.